# Django ORM: как сделать фильтрацию по колонкам одной записи

Tags: python, django-orm, django

Как сделать запрос в Django, который сравнивает поля одной и той же записи?

```
SELECT username, email, date_joined, last_login FROM auth_user
WHERE username=email AND last_login=date_joined
```

Возвращаемые поля не важны

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что-то вроде этого попробуй

```
from django.db.models import F
...

.filter(username=F('email'))
```

http://djbook.ru/rel1.6/topics/db/queries.html#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model

Comment: Работает, спасибо. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model
Как же это я сразу не нашел :)